# Django pagination returns all data after clicking any page number in search result

Tags: python, html, django, search, pagination

I paginated the search result. For the first, query set gives me perfect result , but when i click on any page number, it accepts search key as null and get all data from db. here is the code

Views.py

```
def youtube_search(request):

    query = request.GET.get('q')
    Q = SearchDetail.objects.all().filter(query = query).order_by('-datetime')

    if request.method=='GET':
        page_request_var = 'page'
        page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
        paginator = Paginator(Q, 10)
        try:
            paginated_queryset = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            paginated_queryset = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            paginated_queryset =     paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        'queryset': paginated_queryset,
        'page_request_var': page_request_var,
        'searchKey':query
        }

    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

here is my template

Home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <header>
        <h3 class="h6">Search the blog</h3>
    </header>
    <form action="{% url 'search' %}" class="search-form">
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
        <button type="submit">search</button>
        </div>
    </form>

{% for Q in queryset %}

    {{Q.title}}<br/>
    {{Q.description}}<br/>
    {{Q.datetime}}<br/>
    {{Q.thumbnail}}<br/>

{% endfor %}

<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
          <ul class="pagination pagination-template d-flex justify-content-center">
            {% if queryset.has_previous %}                
            <li class="page-item"><a href="?{{ page_request_var }}={{ queryset.previous_page_number }}" class="page-link"> <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a></li>
            {% endif %}

                  {% for num in queryset.paginator.page_range %}

                        {% if queryset.number == num %}
                         <li class="page-item"><a href="?{{ page_request_var }}={{ queryset.number }}" class="page-link active">{{ num }}</a></li>                       

                        {% elif num > queryset.number|add:'-3' and num < queryset.number|add:'3' %}

                        <li class="page-item"><a href="?{{ page_request_var }}={{ num }}" class="page-link ">{{ num }}</a></li>

                        {% endif %}

                  {% endfor %}
            {% if queryset.has_next %}
            <li class="page-item"><a href="?{{ page_request_var }}={{ queryset.next_page_number }}" class="page-link"> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
            {% endif %}

          </ul>
        </nav>
```

I searched stackoverflow for solutions.None of them answered my question
I tried every piece of code i got from google.help me solve this

Comment: you can use generic `ListView`. with built-in pagination, [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/)

Comment: Can you show me how to do it with ListView.please

Answer (score 0):

generic ListView:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class YoutubeSearchView(ListView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    model = SearchDetail
    paginate_by = 10
    context_object_name = 'search_objects'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q', None)
        if query:
            return SearchDetail.objects.filter(query__icontains=query).order_by('-datetime')
        return SearchDetail.objects.none()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(YoutubeSearchView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['searchKey'] = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return context
```

home.html:

```
{% load mathfilters %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <header>
        <h3 class="h6">Search the blog</h3>
    </header>
    <form action="{% url 'search' %}" class="search-form">
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
        <button type="submit">search</button>
        </div>
    </form>

{% for Q in search_objects %}
    {{Q.title}}<br/>
    {{Q.description}}<br/>
    {{Q.datetime}}<br/>
    {{Q.thumbnail}}<br/>
{% endfor %}

<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination pagination-template d-flex justify-content-center">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <li class="page-item">
                <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}" class="page-link">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
            {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
                {% if page_obj.number == num %}
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a href="?page={{ page_obj.number }}" class="page-link active">
                            {{ num }}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a href="?page={{ num }}" class="page-link ">
                        {{ num }}
                    </a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <li class="page-item">
                <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" class="page-link">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: still,when i click on page 2 ,it is returning me all the database objects instead of returning the second page of searched query

Comment: post the second page url.

Comment: `http://localhost:8000/?page=2` is the second page url and `http://localhost:8000/?q=django` is for the first page.

Comment: use this for `has_next` section: `page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}&q={{ searchKey }}` in your template.

Comment: more than 200 but less than 500

Comment: `ValueError at /
Cannot use None as a query value`   is the result of the update.Is there any way to pass the query back to the view on clicking a page link.If you want to try it yourself hers my github repo : https://github.com/Mahesh61437/youtubeapiUI

Comment: I have 20 objects in the database for each query.I paginated them as 10 per page.the second page says "page not found"

Comment: It worked after i added `&q={{request.GET.q}}` to the has.next and has.previous sections.I tried it before,but it didn't work.But now it worked.Thank you